# Cómo autocompletar en visual studio code

Tags: javascript, vscode, autocompletar

Cómo se consigue que visual studio code autocomplete cosas tan basicas como toLowerCase, toUpperCase, etc Tengo que escribir todo y muchas veces no sé si falta algun paréntesis o valor que añadir

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Revisa: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense

Comment: yo creo que está todo activado pero no me reconoce esas funciones...gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Cuando trabajas con Javascript puro es difícil para tu editor identificar que una variable es un string y que por lo tanto tiene una función como `toLowerCase`, en Javascript cada variable es considerada de tipo any, si quieres mejor soporte de tipos y ayuda de autocompletado te recomiendo que revises Typescript, Javascript con tipos que mejora la experiencia de desarrollar en Javascript en muchos aspectos.

Comment: Cambiando el archivo a typescript tampoco aparece ningún autocompletado. Entonces no habría manera de conseguir ese autocompletado por problema del lenguaje, en este caso javaScript??